# CSS style without HTML selector for label

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML structure;

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    Some Name
</label>
```

My label tag doesn't have any HTML selector.

I need to apply some CSS style for the "Some Name" text. Is there any way to achieve this?

It should work in both IE and Firefox.

Comment: Label is there but I need to apply for my text only that is "Some Name"

Comment: text standing alone cannot be styled as a box, only it's container can be style and apply different font style. what are you trying to actually do for styling. can you clarify ?

Comment: I mean, what do you want to do with the text node? If you want to apply color you could just apply it to the label.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply CSS to `label`

```css
label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" /> Some Name</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that, you will need to wrap it in an HTML element like a `<div>` or an `<a>` to style it.

Comment: really a `<span>` is the appropriate element to wrap it in. But good answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why don't you have a wrapper tag for that label but, I have a suggestions.

- Style the parent tag so that every child element can inherit the parent styles. Like, apply some styles to `<form>` or `<body>` so that every element in those will effect.
- Or, have a separate tag for that label and apply styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a Label tag

HTMl

```
     <label id="myLabel">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
<span>
        Some name
   </span>
 </label>
```

CSS

```
    #myLabel {
color:blue;
}
  span{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: it is already wrapped in a label ... this is a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: you asked about css

Comment: I did not, i asked the OP to clarify what style he wants to aplly ... input is also a child here wich seems to bother him ...  ;)